# Neo4j community version 2.0 fails

Tags: java, neo4j

I got this error:

```
Oct 30, 2013 11:26:03 AM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
INFO: Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
Oct 30, 2013 11:28:11 AM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
SEVERE: Failed to start database.
Oct 30, 2013 11:28:11 AM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
SEVERE: 
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Startup took longer than 120000ms, and was stopped. You can disable this behavior by setting 'org.neo4j.server.startup_timeout' to 0. Error code: 1
at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:186)
at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:86)
at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:49)

Oct 30, 2013 11:28:11 AM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
SEVERE: Failed to start Neo Server on port [7474]
```

---

I am running neo4j at a Linux 64 machine, distro Fedora 19; java version:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

---

Environment variables:

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45"
CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin
```

I cannot figure out what is happening. Any help?

Comment: Did you follow this advice?
>Startup took longer than 120000ms, and was stopped.
>You can disable this behavior by setting 'org.neo4j.server.startup_timeout' to 0.

Comment: Ok, but where? I have scanned all folders, there is no such entry.

Comment: Ok, I have set to 240, no changes. I suppose this behaviour is not due to timeout settings. Log excerpt is at:  http://ur1.ca/fyltv There something that causes this message: org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j Server failed: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, /home/<user_name>/Applications/neo4j-community-2.0.0-M06/data/graph.db

Comment: I've changed JAVA_HOME to "/usr/java/latest" to get all updates and ovoid conflicts, but no changes. I will try lucene index changing.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the data folder and starting again might be a file permission issue

Comment: Yes, I did deleted, but made a fresh install, but it's a good idea, I will try. Ty.

Comment: I deleted lucene index folder...it is working now...

Comment: Yes, as I deleted lucene index, it is working fine, but there is another issue: as I tried to import graph_db to Gephi, I got this message:      org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.UpgradeNotAllowedByConfigurationException: Failed to start Neo4j with an older data store version. To enable automatic upgrade, please set configuration parameter "allow_store_upgrade=true". Curiously, this is already set...BTW, java version is "java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)"...